# Ruby argument error

Tags: ruby, argument-passing

If I hard code the variable **max** below, my program runs with no problems. If I pass an argument in, max sets correctly but gets throws and error. Why is that?

```
max = ARGV[0].to_i

# Ask user for first guess
puts "I am thinking of a number between 1 and " + max.to_s + "."
print "Make your guess: "
guess = gets.chomp.to_i
```

Error Thrown: **`gets': No such file or directory (Errno:: ENOENT)**

Note: The error is fixed by changing **gets** to **STDIN.gets** but why is this needed when without the argument my program works fine?

Further, is there a way to change the default behavior of gets back to **STDIN.gets** for the entire file? Perhaps with one line at the top of the program?

Comment: "but gets throws and error. Why is that" - If you don't tell us what the error is (and on what line), how are we supposed to know what happened and why?

Comment: Added it as you were typing that comment ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Kernel.gets` has some interesting behavior that explains your issue:

http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Kernel.html#method-i-gets

Specifically, it behaves differently depending on whether or not `ARGV` is empty, and if it is *not* empty then it will behave differently from `STDIN.gets`. If you don't want to use `STDIN.gets` explicitly, you might use `max = ARGV.shift` to remove that element before calling `gets`.

Addressing your last question: the best way to force `gets`' behavior to match `STDIN.gets` is probably to make sure `ARGV` is empty before doing anything else, and to make sure it stays that way. However, it may be wiser to continue to simply use `STDIN.gets`, "just to be sure". In cases like this, where unusual and surprising behavior is possible, it is almost always best to write code as explicitly as possible.

Comment: Perfect! Just what I needed! Is there any way to dump the extra arguments if some knucklehead user adds more than one?

Comment: I am begrudingly going to have to agree with your advice on explicit code. It is going to cost me typing a Whopping SIX extra characters for every gets statment tho. *grumble grumble grumble* Thanks for all your help!!

Comment: The `clear` instance method of `Array` is the best way I can think of off the top of my head.

Answer (score 0):

You should use:

`STDIN.gets`

When trying to get user input.